# PIL python library loads only 0 but still displays image

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import  Image


image_path = f"D:\datasets\dataset_game_objects\\1.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path)
image_array = np.array(image)
image.show()
```

I am running following simple code for testing if path to my image  is correct but  I have encouter rather weird error my image opens but when I  transform it into array  i get following output

```
[[[0 4 0]
  [0 4 0]
  [0 4 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [1 0 0]
  [1 0 0]]
 [[0 4 0]
  [0 4 0]
  [0 4 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [1 0 0]
  [1 0 0]]
 [[1 3 0]
  [1 3 0]
  [1 3 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [1 0 0]
  [1 0 0]]
 ...
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [2 1 0]
  [3 2 0]
  [4 3 1]]
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [1 0 0]
  [1 0 0]
  [2 1 0]]
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [1 0 0]
  [1 0 0]
  [1 0 0]]]
```

so I tried PilToTensor() as transformation

```
tensor([[[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

So this is rather weird behavior  the the pictures are all jpgs

Comment: I don't think `np.array(image)` does what you think it does.

Comment: 0 represents black if am not mistaken, when you convert to float tensor its still going to be 0 just with . , so nothing wrong here check your image

Comment: @EdwinCheong that is the pickle image is not black at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already taken into account that `torchvision.transforms.PILToTensor` method changes dimensionality oder. Quoting from the documentation:

```
Converts a PIL Image (H x W x C) to a Tensor of shape (C x H x W).
```

Ref: https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.PILToTensor.html

If yes , could you please share the pic as well, I can give it a go.

P.S: Could've simply commented this but don't have enough points in my profile to do that yet

Comment: Yes I did but it seems that it also causes error that  images are uint8 tensor  so solution is to use ToTensor from transforms library instead  Ty for an idea @Devenda Vyas